# Show Behat features with formatted result in browser in Symfony 3.4

Tags: behat, symfony-3.4

We have installed `behat` and while executing "`bin/behat`" it is executing test feature. But is there any method or option to display results in a browser by accessing URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the output to a file in xml format, you can then open it with any browser: "--no-colors -f junit -o some/folder"
There is also [BehatHtmlFormatterPlugin](https://github.com/dutchiexl/BehatHtmlFormatterPlugin) *"for generating HTML reports from your test results"*